# string input help from keyboard emulator

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have wrote some basic code for a project. I am at the point I am trying to take an input from a RFID reader using a keyboard emulator. The follwing is my code to this point:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char product; //declaring the variable for the switch/case
    int Pay = 0; //Declaring the variable Pay
    int Payment = 0;
    double Total = 0; // Declaring the Final Total variable
    double Subtotal = 0; // Declaring the variable Subtotal
    double Tax = 0; // Declaring the variable Tax
    int m = 0; //counts the amount of times milk is scanned
    int b = 0; //counts the amount of times beer is scanned
    int c = 0; //counts the amount of times candy bar is scanned
    int r = 0; //counts the amount of times rice is scanned


    cout << "Scan the product you desire to purchase: \n";//Asking user to input product purchasing
    cout << "When ready to checkout press the z button.\n\n\n"; //Telling user to press button z to pay

    while(Pay < 1) //Keeps in the loop until pay is increased to 1
    {
        getline(cin, product); //Taking input and assining to the variable product


            if(product == E007C02A55EF918D) 
            {
                cout << "6 pack of Budlight...........$6.49\n"; // If the button b is pushed displays
                Subtotal = Subtotal + Beer; // Calculates the Subtotal and stores it
                Tax = Beer * Taxrate + Tax; // Claculates the total Tax and stores it
                b++;
            }

            else if(product == E007C02A55EF937C)
            {
                cout << "Snickers Bar.................$0.99\n";// If the button c is pusehd displays
                Subtotal = Subtotal + Candy_Bar;
                Tax = Candy_Bar * Taxrate + Tax;
                c++;
            }

            else if(product == E007C02A554A7A8B)
            {
                cout << "1 Gallon of 2% Milk..........$3.99\n";//If the button m is pushed displays
                Subtotal = Subtotal + Milk;
                m++;
            }

            else if(product == E007C02A55CE0766)
            {
                cout << "Box of Brown Rice............$2.79\n";//If the button r is pushed displays
                Subtotal = Subtotal + Rice;
                r++;
            }

            else
            cout << "Invaild product. Please scan a different product.\n";

            if (product == 'z')
            Pay++; //When finished it increases pay to 1 to break the while loop


        Total = Subtotal + Tax; // Claculates the Total

    }
```

I am using MSVS 2010 to compile this code. With this code I can not compile because it says E007C02A55EF918D is undefined. E007C02A55EF918D is the serial number from one of the RFID tags and is what I am trying to input. I know I am having problems with the getline function also, but I am more worried about getting the serial number as an input.

Comment: The compiler needs to know what type is `E007C02A55EF918D`, you are comparing a `char` (product) to something unknown to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` is big enough for a single character (it is usually an 8bit quantity, but don't rely on that).

So your `product` variable can only hold one char.

`E007C02A55EF918D` is an identifier (because it begins with a letter, it is not considered as a number, and because it is not quoted, it is not interpreted as a string).

If you intended `product` and those serial numbers to be 64bit numbers, you'll need to change `product` to be large enough to store them (`uint64_t` for instance), and change the serial numbers in your code to be numbers by prefixing with `0x`. You'll also have to change your input method (`getline` takes strings, so you will need to convert that string to a number - see [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c) for instance).

```
if (product == 0xABCD1234)
```

If you indented both to be strings, then declare `product` with:

```
std::string product;
```

and quote (`""`) the serial numbers. You'll also need to change the last test to:

```
if (product == "z")
               ^ ^
```

You can't compare an `std::string` with a single `char` (`'z'` is a char, `"z"` is a C-style 0-terminated string).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed the `if(product == "E007C02A55EF918D")` and I changed the variable decleration of `product` to `string product:` and my program works like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

Try having it in `""` and use `strcmp()` instead of `==`, like

```
if (!strcmp("E007C02A55EF937C",product))
```

or

```
if (strcmp("E007C02A55EF937C",product)==0)
```

Hope it helped you.

Comment: `strcmp` with only one argument?

Comment: @kittyPL I can't use it becaus eI get an error saying to few arguments in function call

Comment: oops should be if (strcmp("E007C02A55EF937C",product)==0)