# Convert a character to an integer in C++

Tags: c++, string, char

How can I set each character in a string to an integer? This is just the first thing I have to do in order to write a hash function. I have to set each character in a string to an integer so that I can sum their values. Please help! It it something like this??

```
    int hashCode(string s)
{
   int Sum = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
   {
      Sum += (int)s[i];
   }
   return Sum;
}
```

Comment: `strlen(std::string)`?  Say what?

Comment: Something like that, yes. You should look up the string class though to find out how to correctly get the length.

Comment: have you had a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) before you've started to make up your own hash function?

Comment: @moooeeeep: Obviously this is homework.  OP, your teacher may very well teach you to write code like this as you are a beginner, but be aware that this would not be considered production quality code by most C++ teams.

Comment: yes. I am kind of figuring that. But the thing is I am given some code. and told to add to it. so i cant just do whatever I want.

Comment: Duplicate of  [Convert char to int in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029840/convert-char-to-int-in-c-and-c) (second interpretation)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes -- in C and C++, `char` is just a small integer type (typically with a range from -128 to +127). When you do math on it, it'll normally be converted to `int` automatically, so you don't even need your cast.

As an aside, you really don't want to use `strlen(s)` inside the stopping condition for your for-loop. At least with most compilers, this will force it to re-evaluated `strlen(s)` every iteration, so your linear algorithm just became quadratic instead.

```
size_t len = strlen(s);

for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    Sum += s[i];
```

Or, if `s` is actually a `std::string`, as the parameter type suggests:

```
for (int i=0; i<s.size(); i++)
    Sum += s[i];
```

As yet one more possibility:

```
Sum = std::accumulate(s.begin(), s.end(), 0);
```

Comment: +1 `std::accumulate()` -- "you really don't want to use `strlen(s)` inside the stopping condition for your for-loop" IME compilers are smart enough to figure out if they can lift that out of the loop most of the time.

Comment: @bames53: doing a bit of updated testing, I find gcc doing the loop hoisting, but VC++ not.

Answer (score 6):

Characters are usually represented internally by integers, so `s[i]` can be assigned to an integer.

If you have char `'1'`, and want to store int `1`, then you can do `s[i]-'0'`.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for

```
Sum += s[i] - '0';
```

For the general case of converting numbers to strings and vice versa see [this FAQ entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) or, since this was tagged C++, a string stream.

```
string myStream = "45";
istringstream buffer(myString);
int value;
buffer >> value;
```

Comment: No, don't use `atol`. `strtol`, if you really must, but for hashing purposes you might as well not convert at all.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Yeah you're right.  I forgot that you essentially cannot check for failure as it returns 0...

Comment: Cat Plus Plus. But our exercise is to convert them into ascii and then sum the ascii and then divide modulo something. Is there a name for that type of hash function?

Answer (score 0):

The function youre looking for is [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/).

You find it in the header `stdio.h` and it's defined like this

```
int sscanf ( const char * str, const char * format, ...);
```

In your case you would use it like this:

```
string str = "SomeStringWithNumbers";
int s, len;
len = str.length();
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
{
    int status = sscanf( str[i], "%d", &s);
    // Check status if necessary 
 }
```

If your string does **not** only consist of your desired integeer you need to adapt the parameters. You can then modify the first parameter so it points directly to the part of the string where your number lies or you must adapt the format string. Also you should check the return value then.

Answer (score -1):

And the answer is (i think)

```
int i = atoi("5")
```

Btw atoi stance for ascii to Integer.

**Accoarding to Cat Plus Plus atoi isn't supported probably. So you better don't use it then ;)**

Comment: Never use `atoi`. It's broken and cannot communicate errors properly.

Comment: @EdS.: `atoi` is *not* reliable in *any* way.