# size_t convert/cast to string in C++

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

How do I convert an integral value to a `string` in C++?

This is what I've tried:

```
for(size_t i = 0;vecServiceList.size()>i;i++)
{
    if ( ! vecServiceList[i].empty() )
    {
        string sService = "\t" + i +". "+  vecServiceList[i] ;
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [3]' to binary 'operator+'
```

Comment: my first guess is that you need something, e.g. boost:format("%lu") % i, but what was the error?

Comment: `std::to_string((int)var)`

Comment: @7heo.tk I don't see what that has to do with things /at all/. Also, the marked duplicate mentions all integral types perfectly fine, so that's not a problem.

Comment: @sehe my bad, I found this question searching for `size_t` safe alternative to `atoi`. I didn't bother to check if the question was written with "to" or "from".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use a string stream:

```
#include <sstream>

...


for (size_t i = 0; ... ; ...)
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << "\t" << i << vecServiceList[i];

    std::string sService = ss.str();

    // do what you want with sService
}
```