# convert int to char * in C++

Tags: c++, char, int

I want to convert an `int` to `char *`

```
char str[10]=;
int i=567;

str=itoa(i, str, 10)
```

This gives an error on str the third line

`str must have a modifiable lvalue`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

Comment: @Mat i am using char * not string...

Comment: And still, you better convert it to an std::string and then use the. .c_str() method...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
char str[10]; 
int i=567; 
itoa(i, str, 10);
```

Comment: C'mon i had used = Accidently..i wrote in the same way as you wrote in answer

Comment: Check the third line.  itoa takes a char pointer and modifies it.

Comment: @user1391118 C'mon, i wrote it differently from you! =)

Comment: _itoa_s is now suggested as itoa is deprecated