# loop not correctly operated

Tags: c++

This is my code here i am trying to find the biggest length of same length characters at a time like "`a a a bb bb bc sa sa a a`" so answer is 5 for two characters at a time for 5 times adjacently .

this is my code , my question is that when i am trying to take the input , for my first input it is not going to getline but printf in last lines and then it takes a line and prints output

like if i give
5 it writes 1 then it takes getline , but i want it to take getline first rather than printf, in this way for my 5 input it prints 1 and 4 desired outputs .i want 5 desired can you tell me why..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,j;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(j=0;j<a;j++)
    {
        vector<int> v;
        string s;
        getline(cin,s);

        int i,cnt =0;
        for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {

            if(s[i] != ' ')
            {
                cnt++;
            }
            else
            { 
                v.push_back(cnt);
                cnt =0;
            }
        }
        v.push_back(cnt);

        int k=0;
        int ps =0;
        int sp=0;

        while(k<v.size()-1)
        {
            if (v[k+1] - v[k] == 0)
            {
                sp++;
                k++;
            }
            else
            if (sp >= ps)
            {
                ps = sp;
                 k++;
                sp=0;
            }
            else
            {
                k++;
                sp=0;
            }
        }
        if (sp<ps)
        printf("%d",ps+1);
        else
        printf("%d",sp+1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be mixing `scanf` with `getline`, try to only use one or the other (and `getline` is a better option).

What is happening is that `scanf` stops parsing once it has finished reading an `int`. It does not consume the end of line character you type, or anything else you could have entered after that number. So `getline` picks up whatever was left on that first line (possibly just the newline char).
A "quick" but dirty fix would be to change your `scanf` call so that it swallows the whitespace after the `int`:

```
scanf("%d ",&a);
      // ^ notice the space there
```

But that's not a real fix. Use `getline` and a string stream (in `<sstream>`) to get the first number, and your code will work as you intend it to. You'll find examples of using the `istringstream` to extract a number in this FAQ: [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

You might also be interested in this other question:
[Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c), the answers demonstrate ways to split a string that are less error-prone than what you're doing here.

Answer (score 1):

How are you entering everything exactly?  I think the problem may be that your getline() is reading your last [enter] off of the stream, thus automatically putting an empty string into s.  That would result in the 1 you're getting.  Try this for your scanf:

```
scanf("%d\n",&a)
```

That should absorb the [enter].