# Is there a way to test if an input is a number in C++?

Tags: c++, testing, input

Question's all in the title.
I'm making a calculator and I obviously need input. I use the cin>> function but I was wondering if there is a way to test the input to find out if it's a number.
If I enter anything that isn't a number the program crashes. Is there a built in function/operator? Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

Comment: @KillianDS it is not about "converting a number to string", but "checking if an input is a number"

Comment: @rafl: you cannot check if it is a number without at least trying to convert. And most conversion functions offer a "fail" mechanism that you can use here. No need to reinvent the wheel at all.

Comment: @KillianDS, sure, you can use a regex.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y and what does that regex actually do? It tries to interpret the string as a number, sounds much like conversion to me. It's not the method that you use for conversion that matters.

Comment: It does not convert. It matches a string against a pattern. That is quite different from conversion.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y yes, matching or interpretation is the first step in conversion, it is also often the step that contains the failure-checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input operator will only read to an integer if the input *is* a number. Otherwise it will leave the characters in the input buffer.

Try something like this

```
int i;
if (cin >> i)
{
    // input was a number
}
else
{
    // input failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` and `sscanf` are your friends, or just compare if the entered charcode is within the "0"-"9" range

Comment: you should put some examples in your answer.