# Add two string in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

in csharp

```
string s1="12345"
string s2="54321"

public double (string s1,string s2)
{
  convert.todouble(s1) +convert.to-double(s2)
}
```

how i do in c++ because there is no conversion classs

Comment: @valdo: Except that C++'s a high-level programming language too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `boost::lexical_cast` for example.

```
double func (const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    return boost::lexical_cast<double>(s1) + boost::lexical_cast<double>(s2);
}
```

or use `std::stringstream`, `strtod` etc.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers, the easiest way (in C++11 at least) would be:

```
double add(const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2)
{
    return std::stod(s1) + std::stod(s2);
}
```

Comment: if function retrun type is int???so its same???

Comment: If the string contains an `int`, there is also `std::stoi` [and a set of others](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) for that.

Answer (score 4):

If your compiler supports C++11, there is a function `stod` that converts a string to a double.

Your function will be just

```
return std::stod(s1) + std::stod(s2);
```

Comment: if function retrun type is int???so its same???

Answer (score 2):

```
double doubleFromString(const std::string &str)
{
    std::istringstream is(str);
    double res;
    is >> res;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

c++11 contains `std::stod` which converts a `string` to a double. Otherwise you can use `stringstreams` or `boost::lexical_cast<double>`. Therefore your options are:

```
return std::stod(s1) + std::stod(s2); //(c++11 only), or:
return boost::lexical_cast<double>(s1) + boost::lexical_cast<double>(s2); //or:
std::stringstream ss1(s1);
std::stringstream ss2(s2);
double a, b;
ss1>> a;
ss2>>b;
return a+b;
```

Of course you could also go the c route and use `sprintf`.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with using string streams, as you don't need support to c++11.

This article in cplusplus.com answers your question: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/istringstream/

But this is what I would do:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

double function (std::string s1, std::string s2)
{
    std::istringstream iss (std::string(s1 + " " + s2), std::istringstream::in);
    double a, b;
    iss >> a;
    iss >> b;

    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Nice usage of string concatenation to avoid the costly istringstream constructor.

Comment: and i thought that was a naughty hack! thanks :)