# C++ to convert Boost Regex match result to other format

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

How should I convert the boost::regex match result to other format, like integer with below code?

```
string s = "abc123";
boost::regex expr("(\\s+)(\\d+)");
boost::smatch match;
if(boost::regex_search(s, match, expr)) {
  string text(match[0]);
  // code to convert match[1] to integer
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you'd like to have

```
string text(match[1]);
// convert match[2] to integer
```

instead, as `match[0]` is the whole matched thing (abc123 here), so submatch indexing starts at 1.

As for converting to integer part, [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) is convenient to use:

```
string s = "abc123";
boost::regex expr("(\\s+)(\\d+)");
boost::smatch match;
if(boost::regex_search(s, match, expr)) {
  string text(match[1]);
  int num = boost::lexical_cast<int>(match[2]);
}
```