# Error trying to convert from string to int using boost regex match in c++

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I am trying to convert the matched string into a int using regex/boost.
I used this [C++ to convert Boost Regex match result to other format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640284/c-to-convert-boost-regex-match-result-to-other-format/12699630#12699630) as a reference. However when I tried I got `expected primary-expression before ‘int’` and `Symbol 'lexical_cast' could not be resolved` error.

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


int main(){
    string a = "123";
    boost::regex e("123");
    boost::smatch match;

    if (boost::regex_search(a, match, e))
        {
            int number = boost::lexical_cast<int>(match[0]);
            cout << number << endl;
         }
    return 0;
}
```

why am I getting these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot this line:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

Comment: wow. Thanks. i knew it was something silly.
If I want to convert to double/float all I have to do is change the `<int>` to `<double>`, `<float>` right?

Comment: Yes, that'll do it. Any type for which an `operator>>(std::ostream&, TYPE&)` is defined should work.