# convert int to char* to print

Tags: c++, char, int, typeconverter

I want an int value to display in screen as a string. This is for a game I am doing in opengl. I have something like this:

```
char *string = "0"; // to declare

sprintf (label,"%d" ,string); // This prints 0
```

This works perfect to print the 0 in the screen, however as you might understand I want the 0 to be changing. I tried converting int to string and trying to assign this to the char *string, but i think it is not possible. I am a newbie in C++ so I do not know much about I would much appreciate your help with this. What I want to achieve is this:

```
char *string = "0"; // to declare
int number = 90; // declare int to be converted;

sprintf (label,"%d" ,string); // This prints 90
```

I have found converting methods for int to char methods, howevernon have solved my issue. Thank you for all your help in advance.

Comment: What about `printf` with `%d`?

Comment: what is the role of `int number` in all of this?

Comment: There are many ways of converting [string to integers and vice versa][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c

Comment: basically the number will be the score, and this will be changing constantly so I want to refresh the score on screen

Comment: @Scooter: Ask the author before making such a fundamental change to the question. There is nothing to indicate that the question is C only.

Comment: @LokiAstari Well there was this: "Thanks but I am not using just c++ this is a game for opengl and to be able to print this in opengl i need to use it in that format. Thank you!" In rereading I see the _just_ which I missed because the comment came in response to a iostream C++ solution, which I thought meant he was looking for a C solution.

Comment: This answer may help you.

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is print a number to the screen, then you can stream to `std::cout`:

```
#include <iostream>

int nubmer = ....;

std::cout << number;
```

Otherwise, you can stream the number into an `std::ostringstream`, and get the underlying `const char*`:

```
std::strimgstream o;
o << number;
const char* string_ = o.str().c_str();
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not using just c++ this is a game for opengl and to be able to print this in opengl i need to use it in that format. Thank you!

Comment: @juanchopanza The question was originally tagged C++ when you answered it. I retagged it as C when he said he was using C. The downvoter probably saw your C++ answer and didn't realize that you made it before it was retagged.

Comment: @Scooter OP says "I am not using just C++", which implies C++ is OK, as long as one gets a `char*` out of it somehow.

Comment: Yep, I've undone my two downvotes now that this has been explained.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
std::stringstream val;

val << number;

val.str();         // Gets you a C++ std::string
val.str().c_str(); // Gets you a C-String
```

Comment: @Barmar the question was tagged C++, and OP states in a comment "I am not using just C++", which suggests C++ is OK, but in coordination with a C some API.

Answer (score 1):

```
   char label[100] = {"0"};
   printf("%s\n",label);
   int number = 90;
   sprintf(label,"%d",number);
   printf("%s\n",label);
   sprintf(label,"%d",number + 1);
   printf("%s\n",label);
```

output:

```
0
90
91
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I am new in this and I am struggling a little bit thanks!