# How can I convert string to float and back to string using a similar method?

Tags: c++, string, floating-point

How can you convert the string 6.78 to a float?
How can you convert a float 7.89 to a string?

Do both of these questions have similar answers?

Comment: atof() and ftoa() or sprintf() are your friends.

Comment: Do you man single precision float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the standard library `<string>` you have

```
std::string std::to_string(float val)

and

float std::stof (const std::string&  str, size_t* idx = 0)
```

See [stof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/) and [to_string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the AE Drew it works fine
You can also use boost lexical cast if you have boost installed.
Here is an example I found.

http://code-better.com/c/convert-string-integer-using-boost-lexicalcast

I also found that this question has been asked already so you can enjoy a fully contributed answer here:

[How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What is your environment?

If it is Visual Studio and Windows, use atoi() and itoa().