# Fraction addition in C++

Tags: c++

So basically I am trying to do a fraction class. It will take in the fraction from user input and perform an addition. For example, I type in 1  5 and 1  7 , for the addition it will print out 12/35.
Here is my **.h** class:

```
#include <string>
#ifndef _FRACTION_H_
#define _FRACTION_H_

using namespace std;

class Fraction
{
    public:
        Fraction();
        Fraction(int n, int d);
        int getNumerator() const;
        int getDenominator() const;
        void display();
        string to_string();
        Fraction operator+(Fraction &second);
    private:
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
};
```

And this is my **.cpp** file:

```
#include "Fraction.h"
#include <string>
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Fraction::Fraction(){}

Fraction::Fraction(int n, int d)
{
    this->numerator = n;
    this->denominator = d;
}

int Fraction::getNumerator() const
{
    return numerator;
}

int Fraction::getDenominator() const
{
    return denominator;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator+(Fraction &second)
{
    int n1 = getNumerator() * second.getDenominator();
    int n2 = second.getNumerator() * getDenominator();
    int d = getDenominator() * second.getDenominator();
    return Fraction(n1+n2, d);
}
string Fraction::to_string()
{
    return  (getNumerator() + "/" + getDenominator()) ;
}
```

And this is my **main** method:

```
bool get_input(Fraction &fract);

int main()
{
    Fraction fraction1, fraction2;
    if (((!get_input(fraction1)) || (!get_input(fraction2))))
    cout << "Invalid Input!" << endl;
    else 
    {
        // Test harness for Arithmetic Operator Overloading
        Fraction result = fraction1 + fraction2;
        cout << "Addition = " << result.to_string() << endl;
    }

    bool get_input(Fraction& fract)
    {
        int num, den;
        cout << "Enter numerator & denominator (separated by space)" << endl;
        cin >> num >> den;
        if (cin.fail())
        return false;
        Fraction f(num,den);
        fract = f;
        return true;
    }
}
```

It's managed to take in the user input. But however, it does not print out the result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). And please, for the sake of everyone, **never** put `using namespace ...;` in a header. Also, your `operator+` won't work with a temporary or const objects, which is unexpected.

Comment: Sorry what does that means? And how am I supposed to fix my code? I think something went wrong with my toString method

Comment: It does not print out the result? What _does_ it do? Have you stepped through it with your debugger?

Comment: Don't put `using namespace std` into header files. Use it in your cpp-files if you like, but under no circumstances in header files.

Comment: You're right, there is definitely something wrong with your `to_string` function. You're just advancing where the string literal begins, most likely past the end of it. Addition as concatenation does not work with C strings and integers, string literal or not.

Comment: I would say you *could* use it in main. You'd say `.cpp` too @Oswald? I got scared away from it period thanks to this site. I always use `using std::cout;` or sim now :)

Comment: But how should I fix it? I've been stucked here for an hour ago

Comment: @BobbyDigital, I didn't find it that hard to get into the habit of doing that after spending some time here. Now I'm really weighing out whether to use it when `std` is the only thing being used anyway, or as a definitive default, with everything else being qualified. With a little experience, you come to know which names are in use pretty quickly.

Comment: @Gwen concentrate in writing getNumeratorString() and getDenominatorString(), functions which should both return strings containing the string expression of their numeric values. Then you can easily use the combination of both.

Comment: @Gwen google `itoa` or `sprintf` and use one of them in your toString method

Comment: Sorry mind if to show me some example?

Comment: @Rob013, `itoa` is not a standard function. Try `std::to_string`.

Comment: @Gwen Look for it yourself, using Google. Hint: You can append " site:stackoverflow.com" at the end of your Google search, for better results.

Comment: isn't `std::to_string` only allowed in C++ 11 or am I wrong?

Comment: @DanielDaranas, The website filter can be put anywhere in the query :)

Comment: @chris: I agree. I have to say the first time I was warned about it I thought the notion of someone naming their stuff *exactly* like anything in `std` was hilarious. Since I've seen posts doing just that!

Comment: @Rob013, Correct. Prior to that, I would recommend `boost::lexical_cast`, or barring that, `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: @Rob013 There is no `itoa` function, either in C or in C++, and it's almost impossible to use `sprintf` safely.

Comment: @chris Maybe I'm being dense, but I don't see the reserved identifier.  (Or are you referring to `_FRACTION_H_`, which is undefined behavior.)

Comment: @JamesKanze True, but I was only suggesting what to search over google. `std::ostringstream` is definely the best solution.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I was, and it's UB because it's a reserved identifier, or am I missing something (no matter how pedantic)?

Comment: Converting a number to a string and vice versa is a C++ FAQ, actually http://stackoverflow.com/q/5290089/96780

Comment: @chris It's undefined behavior because the standard says so.  But the wording has changed since I learned C++, and the standard does refer to them as "reserved".  (When I learned C++, they were specified as undefined behavior in the description of identifiers, in the language, and not as a library issue.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, That's interesting to know, thanks. I did look at the link again and see how the wording fit the UB in there.

Comment: @BobbyDigital You're even encouraged to do so, so that standard templates can pick them up.  (Any time your class supports an optimized or non-throwing `swap`, for example, you should put a function named `swap` in the same namespace as the class.)

Comment: @chris The standard takes the easy way out; if you violate any of the constraints on using the standard library, it's undefined behavior.  I'm not sure, but I think that since the restriction is given in the library section, it only applies if you include at least one standard header.  (When I was learning C++, the major C++ compiler generated C, and the constraint was part of the language so that the compiler could generate additional symbols without fear of conflict with user defined symbols.  Not a library issue.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, I like their style. Now if only a compiler was brave enough to blow up your house every time you invoked it :p

Comment: @chris For starters, it could refuse to compile the code (distinguishing between system headers and non-system headers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There maybe other problems, but the `Fraction::to_string()`
function is clearly wrong:  the types in the `return` expression
are `int`, `char const*` and `int`.  The result of adding these
is a `char const*`, but given that the string literal is only
two characters long, if the sum of the two `int` is greater than
two, you have undefined behavior.  You need to convert the `int`
to strings first; the simplest way to do this is to use
`std::ostringstream`:

```
std::string
Fraction::to_string()
{
    std::ostringstream results;
    results << numerator << '/' << denominator;
    return results.str();
}
```

Normally, one would expect a compiler error when you misuse
types like this, but for historical reasons: string literals
have type `char const[]`, not `std::string`; `char const[]`
converts almost everywhere to `char const*`; C++ supports
adding integral values to pointers; and std::string has
a constructor which does an implicit conversion from `char
const*`.

Comment: but it told me incomplete type is not allowed

Comment: @Gwen, `#include <sstream>`.

Comment: I feel much relieved by the `s` suffix for string literals coming soon.

Comment: So basically it's my method type is giving an error? Let's say I take in int but I store it as string. Am I explained in the correct way?

Comment: @Gwen `int` and `std::string` (and `char const[]`) are distinct types.  Each has rules concerning their use, and _normally_, if you violate the rules, you get an error from the compiler.  You cannot assign an `int` to a `std::string`, for example.  For historical reasons, however, C++ has a lot of implicit conversions, string literals don't have the type you'd expect, and the type they do have is more or less broken.  So you don't get the compiler error.  But that doesn't mean that the code is correct, nor that it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You use "+" operator between literals (`"/"`) and `int` in your `to_string` method
The compiler is trying to do some implicit conversion and it ends up with a `point` (int + int + char*, best guess is a char*), which is then transformed into a std::string using the correct constructor

Change your method to use `stringstream` (and you'll have finer control on formatting):

```
string Fraction::to_string()
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << getNumerator() << "/" << getDenominator();
    return s.str();
}
```

reference : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/

Comment: oups, looks like I'm too slow