# static_cast vs boost::lexical_cast

Tags: c++, string, boost, casting, lexical-cast

I am trying to concatenate an integer to a known string, and I have found that there are several ways to do it, two of those being:

```
int num=13;
string str = "Text" + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << num) )->str();
```

or I could also use `boost` libraries' `lexical_cast`:

```
int num=13;
string str= "Text" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(num);
```

Is the use of `boost::lexical_cast` more efficient in any way, since I already know the conversion type (`int` to `string`)? Or is `static_cast` just as effective, without having to rely on external libraries?

Comment: IMO, `lexical_cast` is much more readable. Note there is also `std::to_string()` in c++11.

Comment: In your first example, why do you cast to a *pointer*?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I originally wrote the cast was unnecessary in my answer (see the edit history), but it appears that operator << returns ostream& even if the RHS is a ostringstream

Comment: @Armen I know that the cast *itself* is needed but taking the address and casting to *pointer* is convoluted. Just cast to reference. That’s more direct, both syntactically and conceptually.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yeah, I guess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string str = "Text" + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << num) )->str();
```

This is ugly and not easily readable. Adding to this the fact that lexical_cast does almost exactly this underneath we can definitely say that using lexical_cast is "better".

In C++11, however, we have `to_string` overloads.

```
string str = "Text" + to_string(num);
```

Which is the best option provided your compiler supports it.

See also [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

Comment: The cast is needed because the result of `ostringstream() << num` is `ostream&` not `ostringstream&`, so there is no `str()` member.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Oh, OK, didn't think of it. Editing