# C++: conversion of alphanumeric string to Unsigned int in C++

Tags: c++

My class has two unsigned int member variables like

```
unsigned int lowByte;
unsigned int highByte;
```

I need to store alphanumeric string value Ex: "1234##"  or"5635$$" into the above two or any one of the variable...! & I should be able to reconstruct the string value back from the unsigned int..!

Any help please ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you want the transformation to be made? And do you really need to use an `unsigned` to store a byte?

Comment: Of course this is homework.

Comment: i tried atoi() any way that doesnt work for non digit string.. Even tried converting to BCD .. not getting much success..!

Comment: It is not homework.. its kind of requirement.. I have not found such kind of code in Google or any browse.. so thought to work on that.!

Comment: IMO this is related to [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c).

Comment: your string is representation of a number in a number system with base 256. Use standard method to convert the number to base 10. like: `mystring[0]* (256^0) + mystring[1]* (256^1) + mystring[2]* (256^2) + ...` (`^` is `to the power of` operator)

Comment: void MyClass::SetIdString(const string& id)
{
  
   string val = id;
   const char* s = val.c_str();
   
   unsigned int bcd_high = 0xffffffff;
   unsigned int bcd_low = 0xffffffff;
   int i=0;
   while(*s)
   {
      bcd <<= 4;
   if(isdigit(*s))
   {
  char c = *s - '0';
  bcd_high |= c;               //works fine for 0-9
  ++s;
   }
   else
   {
     bcd_low <<= 4;
  char cl = *s - '#';   //works fine for #(0x23) -(0x2d)
  bcd_low |= cl;
  ++s;
   }
    }

   highByte =bcd_high;          //highByte & lowByte are only supported class variables members..!
   lowByte  = bcd_low;
 
}

Comment: `atoi()` successfully converts the strings in your question. This [http://ideone.com/qWi9vj](http://ideone.com/qWi9vj) code works. I suppose you haven't write the universal parser if it's the "kind of requirement", so if you strings have the format "[spaces][digits][characters]" it's enough.

Comment: use `union` as follows: `union mix
{
        int mynum[2];
        char mystr[8];
} mymix={0,0};
`

Comment: unsigned int result = (unsigned int)atoi("1234$$");     Hi. here you will get result as 1234... but how you convert from 1234 to back "1234$$"..?

Answer (score 2):

The posted code produces the same substring: value.substr(0, pos1). Note that [std::string::substr()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) does not modify the object, but returns a new std::string.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string value ="12,fooBar";
    unsigned int myNum;
    std::string myStr;

    const size_t pos1 = value.find(',');    
    if (std::string::npos != pos1)
    {
        myNum = atoi(value.substr(0, pos1).c_str());
        myStr = value.substr(pos1 + 1);
    }

    std::cout << myNum << " and " 
              << myStr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
12 and fooBar
```

If the unsigned int is the only piece required then the following will work:

```
unsigned int myNum = atoi(value.c_str());
```

as atoi() will stop at the first non-digit character (excluding optional leading - or +), in this case the ,.

Comment: This does not work for special char like #,$ etc..