# istringstream to int8_t produce unexpected result

Tags: c++, string, templates, istringstream

After read this [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c), i choose to use istringstream to convert my input string to numerical value.

My code is look like this:

```
<template T>
T Operand<T>::getValue(const std::string &s)
{
    T _value;
    std::istringstream v_ss(s);

    v_ss >> _value;
    return _value;
}
```

When T is int, short, long or float, no problem i get correct value.
But when T is int8_t, this code doesn't work.

By exemple, if my input string is "10", getValue return me a int8_t with value equals 49.

With 49 == '1' in ASCII table, i guess the >> operator just read the first char in input string and stop.

Is there a trick or something i don't understand in the FAQ ?

Comment: You should post some small, compilable test case instead of some code full of errors. But it looks like `int8_t` is treated as a `char` type.

Comment: Iostreams have special overloads for character types. Alas. On the bright side, that means that `cout << '1'` prints a `1` and not `49`.

Comment: @juanchopanza : sry for the little return mistake

Comment: That's not the only one :-) But even without syntax errors, this is not self-contained. [This is what a test-case looks like](http://ideone.com/fdC1oc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `int8_t` is implemented as `char`.

The implementation of the input stream is working like this:

```
char x;
std::string inputString = "abc";
std::istringstream is(inputString);

is >> x;
std::cout << x;
```

The result is 'a', because for `char` the input stream is read char for char.

To solve the problem, provide a specialised implementation for your template method. and reading into a `int`, then check the bounds and convert the value into a `int8_t`.