# C++ : addition of chars in templated class and stringstream conversion to char

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion

I have a tempate class `Operand<T>` whose constructor is :

```
template <typename T>
Operand<T>::Operand(int precision, eOperandType type, std::string val)
   : precision(precision), type(type)
{
     std::istringstream inb(val);
     std::ostringstream err;
     T nb;

     inb >> nb;                                                          
     this->value = nb;
}
```

As the class is templated, it may be used with `char, short int, int, float and double` types, to create operands. My program must be able to execute basic instructions read from a file such as push in a stack, assert, add, mul, div, etc... with these operands.
I have to keep the values within strings from the parsing step to the execution step ; that's to say that when I'm done with parsing I begin to create asked operands of type `T` and I push them into a stack.
Everything is okay, I can execute almost every instruction perfectly except one thing : addition between `Operand` of type `char`.
Let's say I have the following content in a file :

```
push int8(1) // I create a Operand where T = char that contains 1 and I push it                      
                  into my operands stack
push int8(13) // same there but my Operand contains 13

add // This instruction is linked to a operator+ overload, but broadly pops the 2
       previous operands, creates a new Operand where T is the type of the 2 operands
       (char in this case) which must stock the sum (13 + 1 = 14)
dump // displays the content of the stack
```

Thus the output should be `14`, but it displays `9` instead. While debugging I noticed that in my following operator+ overload, tnb1 (1) + tnb2 (13) = 98. Why is that?

```
template <typename T>
IOperand *              Operand<T>::operator+(const IOperand &rhs) const
{
  std::istringstream inb1(this->toString());
  std::istringstream inb2(rhs.toString());
  std::ostringstream res;
  T tnb1, tnb2;
  int l = 1;

  inb1 >> tnb1;
  inb2 >> tnb2;
  if ((tnb1 - tnb2) > std::numeric_limits<T>::max())
    {
      res << tnb1 << " + " << tnb2 << " make an overflow";
      throw CalcExcpt(l, res.str(), "operator+");
    }
  res << tnb1 + tnb2; // here, tnb1 + tnb2 = 98
  if (this->getType() > rhs.getType())
    return Calc::createOperand(this->getType(), res.str());
  return Calc::createOperand(rhs.getType(), res.str());
}
```

Comment: It there some homework out there with this `Operand`? It's the third time I've seen this kind of question today.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127538/istringstream-to-int8-t-produce-unexpected-result