# C++03: _ui64toa_s: error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'errno_t' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++

I have the following line of code:

```
(total_time== 0xAAAABBBB) ? ("") : _ui64toa_s(total_time, myArray, 1024, 10);
```

As the title suggests, I receive this error:

error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'errno_t' to 'const char *'

I am unsure how to convert errno_t to const char *.

I tried to solve it by writing

```
 const char *n = _ui64toa_s(total_time, myArray, 1024, 10);
```

only to see this:
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'errno_t' to 'const char *'

Comment: I suspect that `_ui64toa_s` does not RETURN the string, but an error code. Both parts of the conditional operator must yield the same type.

Comment: @OP: What does `_ui64toa_s` return?

Comment: errno_t.  I am forced to use this instead of the ui64toa, because our stdlib does not have ui64toa defined

Answer (score 0):

[_ui64toa_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0we9x30h.aspx) does not return a string like [_ui64toa](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yakksftt.aspx) does.

Instead it returns an `errno_t` which is defined as `int`.

```
errno_t e = _ui64toa_s(total_time, myArray, 1024, 10);
```

But since you're using C++ I recommend you use [std::to_string](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead.

```
std::to_string(total_time).c_str();
```

You might also want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c).

Comment: unfortunately I am using c++ 03, to_string not available to me