# Convert vector<string> to other types

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, vector

I've a class with`map<string,vector<string>>`.
I want to give a user a member function to receive the value for a key in different formats than std::vector(string):

vector(string),
   string,
   vector(int),
   vector(float) and 
   bool

example:

```
 bool x =  (bool) myClass["dummy_boolean_type"]
 x = myClass["dummy_boolean_type"].as<bool>
 int y = (int) myClass["dummy_boolean_type"]
```

Can someone have an example what is the best way to achieve it ? 
(without a use in Boost)

Comment: `myClass["dummy_boolean_type"]<bool>` that's not valid...

Comment: What would returning `string` or `bool` mean for the user? Like, when would the `bool` be true or false?

Comment: So basically you want to store different types in your map?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)

Comment: However it really unclear for few-times reading, but I've got the idea: author wants `std::vector` to be convertible to types: `bool`, `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<float>`. Am I right, @Shaul ?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy - exactly.  i want to add a member function (i assume it will be a template) so user can ask to have the value for specific key in different format than std::vector(string).

Comment: @Shaul you might to use 2 techniques: `type erasure` or `user-defined conversions` with a wrapper for `std::vector`. I'd answer but unfortunately I dont know how to answer while the question is put on hold.

Comment: @Borgleader how to open this question back?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot provide your class with any member function or functions
that will support the two constructions you want:

```
T x = myClassInstance["key"].as<T>  // (1)
T x =  (T) myClassInstance["key"]   // (2)
```

In the case of (1), the immediate reason is simply that the construction is 
not legal C++. So let's suppose it is replaced by:

```
T x = myClassInstance["key"].as<T>()  // (1a)
```

But this doesn't help, and the reason is the same for both (1a) and (2):

The expression `myClassInstance["key"]` will have to evaluate to some object `e` or reference to such that is returned by:

```
myClass::operator[](std::string const &);
```

This `e` is the `vector<string>` to which `key` maps in your
`map<string,vector<string>` data member of `myClass`. *It is not* `myClassInstance`.

So what you are asking for are member functions of `myClass` that will support
the constructions:

```
T x = e.as<T> // (1b)
T x =  (T) e  // (2b)
```

where `e` is an `std::vector<std::string>`.

Clearly, nothing you can do in `myClass` can address your requirement. In 
(1b) and (2b), `myClass` is nowhere to be seen.

Is there any template member function of `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
template<typename T>
T as() const;
```

that has the behaviour you want for (1b)?

Does `std::vector<std::string>` have any template member function:

```
template<typename T>
operator T() const;
```

that has the behaviour you want for (2b)?

No and No.

**However...**

You *can* implement an `as` template member function of `myClass` that
supports conversions such as you mention. Its signature - of course -
would be:

```
template<typename T>
T myClass::as(std::string const & key) const;
```

and you would invoke it like:

```
T x = myClassInstance.as<T>("key")  // (1c)
```

I'll sketch an implemention that assumes we're content with the 
conversions from `std::vector<std::string>` to:

- `std::string`
- `std::vector<int>`
- `bool`

which will be enough to get you under way.

To convert an `std::vector<std::string> vs` to `std::string` I'll concatenate
the elements of `vs`.

To convert an `std::vector<std::string> vs` to `std::vector<int>` I'll convert each element of `vs` from a decimal numeral, if I can, to the
integer the numeral represents, and return a vector of those integers. Without
prejudice to other policies I'll throw an `std::invalid_argument` exception
when an element doesn't trim to a decimal numeral.

I am spoilt for choice as to what you might mean by converting an `std::vector<std::string>`
to `bool`, so I will arbitrarily say that `vs` is `true` if I can convert it 
to a `vector<int>` of which any element is non-0 and is `false` if I can convert
it to a `vector<int>` in which all elements are 0.

The sketch:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

namespace detail {

template<typename T>
struct convert_to
{
    static T from(std::vector<std::string> const & vs) {
        static constexpr bool always_false = !std::is_same<T,T>::value;
        static_assert(always_false,
            "Calling `convert_to<T>::from` for unimplemented `T`");
        return *(T*)nullptr;
    }
};

template<>
std::string convert_to<std::string>::from(std::vector<std::string> const & vs)
{
    std::string s;
    for (  auto const & e : vs ) {
        s += e;
    }
    return s;
}

template<>
std::vector<int> 
convert_to<std::vector<int>>::from(std::vector<std::string> const & vs)
{
    auto lamb = [](std::string const & s) {
        std::size_t lastoff = s.find_last_not_of(" \t\f\v\n\r");
        int i;
        try {
            std::size_t nlen;
            i = std::stoi(s,&nlen);
            if (nlen <= lastoff) {
                throw std::invalid_argument("");
            }
        }
        catch(std::invalid_argument const & e) {
            throw std::invalid_argument(
                "Cannot convert \"" + s + "\" to int");
        }
        return i;
    };
    std::vector<int> vi;
    std::transform(vs.begin(),vs.end(),std::back_inserter(vi),lamb);
    return vi;
}

template<>
bool convert_to<bool>::from(std::vector<std::string> const & vs)
{
    auto vi = convert_to<std::vector<int>>::from(vs);
    for (auto const & i : vi) {
        if (i) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

} // namespace detail


struct myClass // Your class
{
    // Whatever...

    std::vector<std::string> & operator[](std::string const & key) {
        return _map[key];
    }

    template<typename T>
    T as(std::string const & key) {
        return detail::convert_to<T>::from(_map[key]);
    }

    // Whatever...

private:
    std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>> _map;
};
```

The one take-away point here is the use of `template<typename T>
detail::struct convert_to`, with its solitary static member function:

```
T from(std::vector<std::string> const & vs)
```

which in the default instantiation will provoke a `static_assert` failure
reporting that no conversion to `T` from `std::vector<std::string>` has been
defined.

Then, for each type `U` to which you want a conversion, you have just to
write a specializing definition:

```
template<>
U convert_to<U>::from(std::vector<std::string> const & vs);
```

as you see fit, and the construction (1c) will use it as per:

```
template<typename T>
T myClass::as(std::string const & key) {
    return detail::convert_to<T>::from(_map[key]);
}
```

Here's an illustrative progam you can append to the sketch:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
static void print_vec(std::vector<T> const & v)
{
    cout << "{ ";
    for (auto const & e : v) {
        cout << e << " ";
    }
    cout << "}\n";
}

static void print_vec(std::vector<std::string> const & v)
{
    cout << "{ ";
    for (auto const & e : v) {
        cout << '\"' << e << "\" ";
    }
    cout << "}\n";
}

int main()
{
    myClass f;
    f["int_vec"] = vector<string>{"0","1 "," 2"};
    cout << "f[\"int_vec\"] = "; print_vec(f["int_vec"]); 
    f["true_vec"] = vector<string>{"0"," 1 ","0"};
    cout << "f[\"true_vec\"] = "; print_vec(f["true_vec"]);
    f["false_vec"] = vector<string>{"0"," 0","0 "};
    cout << "f[\"false_vec\"] = "; print_vec(f["false_vec"]);
    f["not_int_vec0"] = vector<string>{"0","1","2",""};
    cout << "f[\"not_int_vec0\"] = "; print_vec(f["not_int_vec0"]);
    f["not_int_vec1"] = vector<string>{"0","@","2",};
    cout << "f[\"not_int_vec1\"] = "; print_vec(f["not_int_vec1"]);
    f["not_int_vec2"] = vector<string>{"0"," 1$","2",};
    cout << "f[\"not_int_vec2\"] = "; print_vec(f["not_int_vec2"]);
    cout << "f.as<string>(\"int_vec\") = \"" 
        << f.as<string>("int_vec") << '\"' << endl;
    cout << "f.as<string>(\"true_vec\") = \"" 
        << f.as<string>("true_vec") << '\"' << endl;
    cout << "f.as<string>(\"false_vec\") = \"" 
        << f.as<string>("false_vec") << '\"' << endl;
    cout << "f.as<string>(\"not_int_vec0\") = \"" 
        << f.as<string>("not_int_vec0") << '\"' << endl;
    cout << "f.as<string>(\"not_int_vec1\") = \""
        << f.as<string>("not_int_vec1") << '\"' << endl;
    cout << "f.as<string>(\"not_int_vec2\") = \""
        << f.as<string>("not_int_vec2") << '\"' << endl;
    vector<int> va = f.as<vector<int>>("int_vec");
    cout << "f.as<vector<int>>(\"int_vec\") = "; 
    print_vec(f.as<vector<int>>("int_vec"));
    cout << boolalpha << "f.as<bool>(\"true_vec\") = " 
        << f.as<bool>("true_vec") << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << "f.as<bool>(\"false_vec\") = " 
        << f.as<bool>("false_vec") << endl;
    try {
        cout << "f.as<vector<int>>(\"not_int_vec0\")...";
        auto b = f.as<vector<int>>("not_int_vec0");
        (void)b;
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument const & e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    try {
        cout << "f.as<vector<int>>(\"not_int_vec1\")...";
        auto b = f.as<vector<int>>("not_int_vec1");
        (void)b;
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument const & e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    try {
        cout << "f.as<vector<int>>(\"not_int_vec2\")...";
        auto b = f.as<vector<int>>("not_int_vec2");
        (void)b;
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument const & e) {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    // char ch = f.as<char>("int_vec"); <- static_assert fails
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
f["int_vec"] = { "0" "1 " " 2" }
f["true_vec"] = { "0" " 1 " "0" }
f["false_vec"] = { "0" " 0" "0 " }
f["not_int_vec0"] = { "0" "1" "2" "" }
f["not_int_vec1"] = { "0" "@" "2" }
f["not_int_vec2"] = { "0" " 1$" "2" }
f.as<string>("int_vec") = "01  2"
f.as<string>("true_vec") = "0 1 0"
f.as<string>("false_vec") = "0 00 "
f.as<string>("not_int_vec0") = "012"
f.as<string>("not_int_vec1") = "0@2"
f.as<string>("not_int_vec2") = "0 1$2"
f.as<vector<int>>("int_vec") = { 0 1 2 }
f.as<bool>("true_vec") = true
f.as<bool>("false_vec") = false
f.as<vector<int>>("not_int_vec0")...Cannot convert "" to int
f.as<vector<int>>("not_int_vec1")...Cannot convert "@" to int
f.as<vector<int>>("not_int_vec2")...Cannot convert " 1$" to int
```

(gcc 5.1, clang 3.6, C++11)