# Retrieving code points using Boost.Locale library

Tags: c++, boost, unicode, locale

From a given Unicode string I wanted to retrieve the list of [*code points*](https://unicode.org/glossary/#code_point) that make up the string. To do so I copied the following example from Boost's [character iteration example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/locale/doc/html/boundary_analysys.html#boundary_analysys_segments_basics) :

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace boost::locale::boundary;

int main()
{
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    std::string text = "To be or not to be";

    // Create mapping of text for token iterator using global locale.
    ssegment_index map(character, text.begin(), text.end(), gen("en_US.UTF-8"));

    // Print all "words" -- chunks of word boundary
    for (ssegment_index::iterator it = map.begin(), e = map.end(); it != e; ++it) {
        std::cout <<"\""<< * it << "\", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It returns me characters (which are different from code points as per Boost's documentation) like this :

```
"T", "o", " ", "b", "e", " ", "o", "r", " ", "n", "o", "t", " ", "t", "o", " ", "b", "e",
```

I read that using the `to_unicode` function in [boost::locale::util::base_converter class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/locale/doc/html/classboost_1_1locale_1_1util_1_1base__converter.html#a27181b314e09f62ae9ea8fcd30d4e7c4) you can retrieve code points of a given string. But I am not sure how. I tried the following code, but no help:

```
for (ssegment_index::iterator it = map.begin(), e = map.end(); it != e; ++it) {
    std::cout << "\"" << * it << "\", ";
    boost::locale::util::base_converter encoder_decoder;
    virtual uint32_t test1 = encoder_decoder.to_unicode(it->begin(), it->end() );
}
```

It returns 'Type mismatch' error. I think the parameters of `to_unicode()` function must be something different

I am considering to use only Boost to retrieve *code points* than existing solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c) or [here](http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-utf8-char-to-codepoint) because Boost provides lots of useful functions to identify *line breaks*, *word breaks*, *etc* in all sorts of languages.

Answer (score 1):

To get the codepoints you can use the `boost::u8_to_u32_iterator`. This is as a UTF-32 character is equal to its codepoint.

```
#include <boost/regex/pending/unicode_iterator.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void printCodepoints(std::string input) {
    for(boost::u8_to_u32_iterator<std::string::iterator> it(input.begin()), end(input.end()); it!=end; ++it)
        std::cout <<"\""<< * it << "\", ";
}

int main() {
    printCodepoints("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```