# convert vector string with decimal value to integer

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector string with decimal value I want to convert it to integer like that **67.35 ----> 6735** atoi is not working ?

```
int n;   
std::vector<std::string> value;   
value= "67.35"
```

I want n to be **6735** 
I know I can write a long code to do that but I am asking if that is already done.

Comment: `std::vector value;` nah.

Comment: @LogicStuff formatting error. The `<std::string>` has been eaten because of the `<>`.

Comment: Ok, but the assignment after?

Comment: @LogicStuff yep, that one is plain wrong :)

Comment: `atoi` converts integers not floats.

Comment: What's a "vector string"?

Answer (score 2):

Is there any chance this might be your solution? Hope this helps.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>

int main() 
{    
    std::string sf = "42.2";     
    std::string si = "42";    
    float f = boost::lexical_cast<float>(sf); //f is 42.2    
    int i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(si);  //i is 42 
}
```

---

**You can check these also:**

[How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/)

[How do I convert vector of strings into vector of integers in C++?](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/)

---

> "Anyway, the *real* answer is to use C++'s `stof` and `stoi`. The dupe is very thorough." (by "Lightness Races in Orbit" in comments)

**Links:**
[stof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/)
[stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/)

Comment: Using boost to convert a string to a number seems slightly overkill. This is a basic C/C++ feature.

Comment: @pie3636: What is "C/C++"? Actually, lexical_cast is much more flexible and is able to optimise where your use of antiquated `atoi` from the C standard library is not. You can also use it in generic code. This is not overkill; it is idiomatic and commonplace in C++.

Comment: C/C++ was meant to say that the `atoi()` and `atof()` functions are a part of the standard C library, and therefore happen to exist in C++ too. OP's question leads me to believe they don't have much experience with C++ or possibly programming in general, so my first answer would certainly not be to install a new library, which might throw them off even more; sure, performance is important, but here it's basic functionality OP is asking for.

Comment: @pie3636: It is much more basic to use lexical_cast than it is to dabble with the C library and all its foibles. `yum install boost-devel` done.

Comment: Anyway, the _real_ answer is to use C++'s `stof` and `stoi`. The dupe is very thorough.

Comment: Not everyone is programming under Linux :)

Comment: I updated the answer according to your contributions. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a vector if you're only going to store one value. The most straightforward way to do it would be:

```
#include <string> // This needs to be in your headers

float n;
std::string value = "47.65";
n = stof(value) // n is 47.65. Note that stof is needed instead of stoi for floats
```

If you need several values, this is how you would do it:

```
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> values;
values.push_back("47.65");
values.push_back("12.34");
//...

std::vector<float> floatValues;
for (int i = 0; i <= values.size(); i++) {
    floatValues.push_back(stof(values[i]));
    // intValues is a vector containing 47.65 and 12.34
}
```

If you're looking to remove the decimal places in your strings before parsing them, you can use the following code:

```
#include <algorithm> // This also needs to be in your headers
#include <string>

int n;
std::string value = "47.65";
std::replace(value.begin(), value.end(), '.', '')
n = stoi(value) // n is 4765. This time we're using atoi since we have an int
```

Comment: Prefer C++, not C.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11089801/560648