# Hex to String with a bit of trick

Tags: c++, type-conversion

First of all, yes I know about [FAQ Converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1).
But I don't need that kind of type-conversion (I hope!).
We have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

struct My_Data{
  uint16_t data;
};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  My_Data data{ 0x12 }; // data = 0x0012
  stringstream ss;
  ss << std::hex << static_cast<int>(data.data);
  string str_data{ ss.str() };
  cout << str_data;  // It will print 12, but I want 0012

  return 0;
}
```

My solution was [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), I just wondering if there is another solution too.
because the main data type in the project is `std::vector<uint8_t>`, so is there any possible short way to get `0012` with `std::vecotr<uint8_t>`?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your code [does not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c774bab0d31d40b).  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry, here you go.

Comment: Have you investigated [iomanip](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip) and `setfill` and `setw`?

Comment: The last sentence doesn't relate to the code in the question. The code shows outputting a value of type `unit16_t`; the last sentence talks about a `vector<uint8_t>` that doesn't appear in the code.

Comment: I want `0012` to be in a value, not just to print it. It's for packet structures and etc.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method to make a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` from an `std::uint16_t` in hex representation with width 4 and zero padded would be something like so

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

std::vector<std::uint8_t> make_hex_vector(std::uint16_t val)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << val;
    auto str = ss.str();
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> ret(str.begin(), str.end());
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks, while you were writing that, i was writing too ;).

Comment: Also, as I said, I want `0012` not `12`

Comment: Finished edit :)

Comment: Now, you understood me :). thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `stringstream` to do this. There are stream manipulators that do all the adjustments you're looking for.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    std::uint16_t data = 0x12;
    std::cout
        << std::setw(6) // set output field width to 6
        << std::hex // write output as hexadecimal value
        << std::setfill('0') // pad with zeros
        << std::showbase // show the prefix for the base (0x)
        << std::internal // insert the padding between the prefix and the value
        << data
        << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't want the "0x", remove `std::showbase` and change the field width to 4.

To answer the question in the last sentence, just use the same manipulators to write out the value of each `uint8_t` in the `vector`.

If, as one of the answers assumes, you're looking for putting the characters into a `std::string`, that's where you'd use a `std::stringstream` instead of `std::cout`.

Comment: Great. Now with `stringstream` I can store `0012` in a `string`. Thank you.